# Quickbooks sdk- Extract customer email

Tags: sdk, quickbooks

I am using the Quickbooks sdk from consolibyte and am trying to extract the email address from the customer query.  Here is the code:

```
$CustomerService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Customer();
$customers = $CustomerService->query($this->Context, $this->realm, "SELECT * FROM Customer ");
```

When I do a print_r($customers) I can see the email address, but am unable to get because it is protected.

How do i get that data?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are getters and setters that exactly match the XML/JSON field/node names.

```
$email = $Customer->getPrimaryEmailAddr()->getAddress();
```

Or:

```
$email = $Customer->getXPath('//Customer/PrimaryEmailAddr/Address');
```

Similarly, for sets:

```
$Addr = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_PrimaryEmailAddr();
$Addr->setAddress('keith@consolibyte.com');
$Customer->setPrimaryEmailAddr($Addr);
```

You can refer to [Intuit's docs](http://developer.intuit.com) for field names.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added your recommendation: $email = $Customer->getPrimaryEmailAddr->getAddress();  and I got this error:  Notice: Undefined property: QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Customer::$getPrimaryEmailAddr i